# undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError' with MinGW

Tags: python, python-2.7, gcc, mingw, cpython

I am compiling a C dll in windows with MinGW using the following instructions:

```
"C:\GNAT\2015\bin\gcc.exe" -shared -c -IC:\Python27\include *.c
"C:\GNAT\2015\bin\gcc.exe" -shared -Wall -O3 -IC:\Python27\include -L./ -l dependency_lib -LC:\Python27\libs *.o -o mylib.pyd -lpython27
```

I get several of these errors during the linking:

```
(.text+0x5a2): undefined reference to `_imp__PyExc_TypeError'
(.text+0x69f): undefined reference to `_imp___Py_NoneStruct'
```

I tried converting the .lib into a .a but I get:

```
/libpython27.a: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
```

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the MinGW compiler needs a python27.a and not a python27.lib. However, **the way the .lib is generated is very important**. For me, the only way it worked was:

1. Get python27.dll. I got it from "C:\GNAT\2015\bin\python27.dll". It may also be in "windows/system32".
2. Generate a .def file with pexport. **Forget about other options like using sed** it did not worked for me. Run pexports.exe python27.dll > python27.def
3. Use dlltool from MinGW:
   dlltool --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib libpython27.a
4. Place the generated libpython27.a in C:\Python27\libs and don't forget to add this path to your gcc command with -LC:\Python27\libs

**NOTE: the -lpython27 option in gcc must be at the end.**

[Source](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/06/28/compiling-python-extensions-with-distutils-and-mingw/)